# How to restrict the ajax call from out side of the browser in django

Tags: ajax, django

i am working in a project, there is no user authentication and authorization. Bascially i am calling ajax in client side and it executes a view in django and return a json out. How can i validate this request is only coming from browser and how to restrict the if this not coming from the browser or any manual script?

Comment: You could generate a hash and include it in the template, that way you could restrict who has access to the ajax call based on who has a valid hash, that would not restrict calls made from curl or other mechanisms but in order to do those calls you would have to know the apps secret key, I would do it hashing the session id and checking in the ajax view if it matches the one made by the ajax call

Comment: @javiercf I appreciate your comment i am too thinking this. But i am also thinking if i include any varible with a secret hash key then that will be visible in the web page right? is there any way to hide the hash variable inside the django template?

Comment: You could make it a data attribute in some obscure element

Comment: I just updated my answer with a more thorough example of what I just proposed

Answer (score 3):

You can use `request.is_ajax()` method

> **HttpRequest.is_ajax()**
>
> Returns True if the request was made via an XMLHttpRequest, by checking the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header for the string 'XMLHttpRequest'. Most modern JavaScript libraries send this header. If you write your own XMLHttpRequest call (on the browser side), you’ll have to set this header manually if you want is_ajax() to work.
>
> If a response varies on whether or not it’s requested via AJAX and you are using some form of caching like Django’s cache middleware, you should decorate the view with vary_on_headers('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') so that the responses are properly cached.

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax)

Im updating my answer to fit what we commented above

**In your views**

```
from django.core import signing
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest

class BrowserView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'yourtemplate.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(BrowserView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['token'] = signing.dumps(self.request.session_id)
        return ctx

class AjaxView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            try:
                sign = signing.loads(self.request.GET.get('token'), max_age=(20))
                if sign == self.request.session_id:
                    ## return ajax
                return HttpResponseBadRequest('You are not authorized to see this page')
            except signing.BadSignature:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest('You are not authorized to see this page')

        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('You are not authorized to see this page')
```

**In your template**

In this case I used a meta tag, but you get the idea

```
<meta name="validation" content="{{token}}" />
```

**In your javascript**

```
var t = document.querySelector("meta[name='validation']").getAttribute('content');
$.ajax({
    url:'yoururl',
    data: yourData + '&token=' + t,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response){
       // do whatever
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah...This will work, but it will just check the it's a ajax call or not. I am thinking to restrict the output other than the browsers, like we can easily mimic in the developer tool in the browser or write a javascript function to get all the output from outside of webapp.

Comment: Yeah, geting session id and comapring will work and i tried that but what i want is how can i get that without leaking it in the template if we can go to the source page anyone can easily take out the session id in the meta tag? Like in php we can write a simple script in the head and get the variable pass it to the compare in php there is no way the secret key to leak but in django?. That's what i want, is ther any way to hide the variable in django tempalate and we have to access it via views in the server side? And Thanks for spending time on this :)

Comment: thing is that session id is hashed with your secret key, and the ajax view checks if it was issued in the last 20 seconds in my example, you can change that to suiit your needs, so if say I view the source and get the token, and then do a curl, the session id for the curl would change thus would be invalid... so hiding it more wouldn't have any advantages, Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signing/) for more info and there is no way I can think of to include python functions inside templates other than using jinja2

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to 100% prevent this, but there are some things you can do:

- a set-cookie header w/some unique ID on the page, but not on API responses.
- if the cookie isn't received by your API, return a 401.
- tracking API calls per unique ID could be a good indicator of "proper" usage.
- associate IDs w/IPs.
- the tracking metrics can be combined w/a threshold that blocks requests if exceeded.
- you can check the referrer header (easy to spoof).
- finally, lookup the `is_ajax` method of Django's, but this just checks for an XMLHttpRequest header (again, easy to spoof).